# How can I create a non sequential sequence like 1.1/1.2/2.1/2.2 and so on with vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project that requires that I use a non sequential sequence that restarts everyday. Like this:

```
13/11/2017

1.1

1.2

2.1

2.2

3.1
```

And then starts over from 1.1 on the next day.

I'm not really sure what to do in this case. Use an array? Set an Excel column with those values? Use an event?

Can someone help me?

Here's the code so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() 'Guardar Banho Grelhas
    Dim LastRow As Long, CR As Long, CRG As Long, CRP As Long, CRE As Long, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, rgr As Long, rgp As Double, rge As Long, Ar As Variant, n As String, x As Long, d As Long, PRG As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Banho Grelhas")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("STOCK Grelhas")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("STOCK Pyr")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("STOCK Et")
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Banho Grelhas
        CR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        PRG = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Previous Row STOCK Grelhas
        CRP = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Current Row STOCK Pyr
        CRE = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Current Row STOCK Et
        CRG = PRG + 1 'Current Row Grelhas
        rgr = TextBox6.Value 'Grelhas a remover
        rgp = 17.5 * 0.8 'Pyrolidona a remover
        rge = 17.5 * 0.2 'Ethylenodiamina a remover
        n = "001"
        x = Replace(Date, "/", " ")
        d = x & n
        Ar = Sheets("Banho Grelhas").Range("K1:K120").Value

        ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = d
        ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox26.Text 'ID Carbonação
        ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = ws2.Range("A" & CRG) 'ID Grelhas
        ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBox6.Text 'Quantidade Grelhas / Banho
        ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = ws3.Range("A" & CRP) 'ID Pyr
        ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = ws4.Range("A" & CRE) 'ID ET
        ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = "1,1"
        ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = TextBox5.Text 'TETRA
        ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") 'Data / Hora introdução
        ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = Date

        'Nº Banho
        If InStr(ws.Range("G" & CR).Value, ",1") > 0 Then
            ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("G" & CR).Value + 0.1
        Else
            ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("G" & CR).Value + 0.9
        End If

        'ID Banho
        If ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("J" & CR).Value Then
            ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("A" & CR).Value + 1
        Else
            ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = d
        End If

        Do While rgr > 0
            If ws2.Range("H" & CRG).Value < rgr Then
                rgr = rgr - ws2.Range("H" & CRG).Value
                ws2.Range("H" & CRG).Value = 0
                NRG = CRG + 1
            Else
                ws2.Range("H" & CRG).Value = ws2.Range("H" & CRG).Value - rgr
                rgr = 0
            End If
        Loop

        Do While rgp > 0
            If ws3.Range("H" & CRP).Value < rgp Then
                rgp = rgp - ws3.Range("H" & CRP).Value
                ws3.Range("H" & CRP).Value = 0
                CRP = CRP + 1
            Else
                ws3.Range("H" & CRP).Value = ws3.Range("H" & CRP).Value - rgp
                rgp = 0
            End If
        Loop

        Do While rge > 0
            If ws4.Range("H" & CRE).Value < rge Then
                rge = rge - ws4.Range("H" & CRE).Value
                ws4.Range("H" & CRE).Value = 0
                CRE = CRE + 1
            Else
                ws4.Range("H" & CRE).Value = ws4.Range("H" & CRE).Value - rge
                rge = 0
            End If
        Loop

TextBox4.Value = Null
TextBox5.Value = Null
'TextBox6.Value = Null
TextBox26.Value = Null
TextBox27.Value = Null

End Sub
```

Comment: The precise problem is very unclear... why can't you, for example, copy and paste the values as many times as needed?

Comment: @Vegard The project I'm working on is going to be used to "track" stocks and production. I've been instructed that for every new product that's produced it's number can't be 1 or 2 or 3 and so on. It has to be specifically 1.1 or 1.2 or 2.1 and so on. I could have the operator fill in a textbox with those values but then they might forget which was the last one and that would be a huge problem. That's why I'm trying to make it somewhat automatic. Would I be able to use some kind of math function for this?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a procedure & userform (typically called from a button) that accepts whatever data you want to enter and then enters that data into the worksheet along with these numbers.

Comment: Or a less robust solution that requires much less code: lock the sheet and add a clickable button that unlocks the sheet & adds these numbers and a relevant heading for where to input information.

Comment: @Vegard My bad. Edited the post and added the code I have so far. It might be a little messy.

Comment: You want the number sequence to appear under the date in column `I`?

Comment: @Vegard I want it to show up in column `G`, since it's going to be bound to the rest of the process.

Comment: Your code looks robust enough, I am not sure what your trouble is? Pasting an array should work, but you can also just manually set 6 rows in column G to those values. Have you had some difficulty already trying to achieve this, and if so, what tripped you up?

Comment: I tried to use an array. What's troubling me is figuring out how to restart the sequence then I advance to the next day. It's been some time since I used vb.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't the code called every time someone pushes a button?

Comment: @Vegard The code works everytime someone pushes a button. However I still can't get it to output the sequence I need.

Comment: What output do you get then?

Comment: I get a 1, 2, 3, 4... sequence.

Comment: You have an array containing `{1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2}` and so on, but the output is `1, 2, 3 ,4` ??

Comment: Yes. I turned a column range into an array.

Comment: This is confusing. I think you need to update the question to also include the code that tries to output your desired sequence. Also, you should list a screenshot or something similar of the desired output and then a separate screenshot of the actual output.

Comment: Also more detail about the sequence - should the entire sequence be pasted every time the button is pressed, or just some of it? In the latter case, which part of the sequence and what are the criteria for determining which part?

Comment: @Vegard Hey! I managed to find a way around the issue from yesterday without using an array. I'm having some trouble getting it to reset everyday tho. Any suggestion? Updated the code on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the contents of all your variables, but based on your code I am assuming this will work as intended:

```
'ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = "1,1"

'Nº Banho
If Format(ws.Range("I" & CR).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
    If InStr(ws.Range("G" & CR).Value, ",1") > 0 Then
        ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("G" & CR).Value + 0.1
    Else
        ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("G" & CR).Value + 0.9
    End If
Else
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = "1,1"
End If
```

It looks like you're using `CR` as the previous line, based on how you appear to be checking whether the previous sequence-value ends in `",1"` or not.

The same logic can be extended to finding out whether this is a new day or not (and conversely, whether to reset the sequence). The logic I added is primarily this line:

`If Format(ws.Range("I" & CR).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") Then`

Which is to say, `if the datestamp in the previous line is the same as today's datestamp` it proceeds with the code that increments the value. In reverse (the outtermost `Else`), this means that if the datestamps **do not match** - meaning the line we're adding has a datestamp that isn't the same as the datestamp in the previous line - we've reached a new day and the sequence has to be reset.

You'll also see that I commented out the line that initially sets the value of col `G`, as it looks like this line will at some point in time override a legitimate value.

Comment: Tried the code you suggested and it worked as expected. Just one last question. Is there any know error that will make Excel stop working? I added a CommandButton that inputs the data into the sheets and also saves the file at the same time. It works fine, but sometimes, makes Excel stop working. Any idea why?

Comment: @Barbaaz There's nothing in your code that stands out to me. I'm not so experienced as to really speak to these things, but there might be some object usage that makes Excel eventually exceed its memory limit. It can be tricky to find those, and it might not even be the case at all. Sorry I can't be more help. If you are able to find a way to reproduce it somewhat consistently, you should post a new question about it and include all your code.